# Ошибка при работе драйверов для звука

Tags: windows, драйвер, аудио

Недавно переустановил, установил все драйверы, но когда дошла рука до драйвера для звука выдавал ошибку. Диск родной, скачивал и с интернета драйверы на звуковую плату и просто Realtek, всё равно при установке выдавал ошибку. В диспетчере устройств устройства помечены восклицательным знаком. Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Звук  PCI или встроенный?

Answer (score 1):

Жмем маус2 на мой компьютер, переходим во вкладку свойства системы, выбираем вкладку оборудывание, переходим во вкладку диспетчер устройств, выбираем тип устройства с воскл знаком, жмем на нём маус2, далее сново в свойства, потом переходим во вкладку сведения, выделяем код,жмем ctrl+c, идем на сайт [devid.info](http://devid.info/), вставляем наш код-жмем return, выбираем нужный драйвер - качаем и устанавливаем! В случае если драйвер не найден, во вкладе сведения, меняем "Код экземпляра устройства"НА ^ код (ID) оборудывания, так же копируем коды и ищем наш драйвер до тех пор пока он найдется) Если совсем все сложно!! Берем soft-driverpack, устанавливаем прогоняем систему, и устанавливаем нужные драйвера!